# cast array<struct<key:string,value:array<string>>> into map<string,array<string>>

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, presto

I have a table like

```
name            string                                      
one_key_value   array<struct<key:string,value:array<string>>                    
two_key_value   array<struct<key:string,value:array<string>>
```

and want to convert it to

```
name            string                                      
one_key_value   map<string,array<string>>                       
two_key_value   map<string,array<string>>
```

In presto I use

```
SELECT name, 
MAP(TRANSFORM(one_key_value, kv -> kv.key), TRANSFORM(one_key_value, kv -> kv.value)) AS one_key_value, 
MAP(TRANSFORM(two_key_value, kv -> kv.key), TRANSFORM(two_key_value, kv -> kv.value)) AS two_key_value
FROM table_a;
```

In hive I use

```
SELECT name,
map(k1,v1) AS one_key_value, 
map(k2,v2) AS one_key_value
FROM table_a 
lateral view inline(one_key_value) t1 as k1,v1
lateral view inline(two_key_value) t2 as k2,v2;
```

The count in hive is a lot higher as compared to presto, I guess it's because one key has lot of values and they are being exploded to different rows in hive. Is there a way to make the hive query similar to the presto query.

Comment: Are you trying to convert `array<struct<key:string,value:array<string>>` to `map<string,array<string>> ` or `struct<key:string,value:array<string>` to `map<string,array<string>> `

Comment: @karma4917 array<struct<key:string,value:array<string>> to map<string,array<string>>